# How to interpret these PPI numbers in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, dpi, ppi

Illustrator gives me the resolution of 33x74 PPI - I'm used to seeing 300DPI, or something similar where it only displays one number.  What's up with this 'a x b' PPI reading? How should I interpret this?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Illustrator giving two values for ppi for a linked raster image, only when rotated?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39318/52050)

Answer (score 1):

The image is just squashed. That happens when you do not uniformly scale the image, but only on one axis.

Comment: Negative - The image is not scaled at all. it's simply 'placed' into the document at full size

Comment: @Melissa the image must be transformed somehow (either rotated or non-uniformly scaled), that is the only time (AFAIK) it will show two values.